# Calculate SUMs based on currency

Tags: mysql, sum

I need to get the total `SUM` from all currencies' values in below query, right now I get 3 *(or 4 - depending on the currencies in the DB)* results, but need the total only.

Please see this <kbd>[**sqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4841f9/2)</kbd>

The query is:

```
select 
case when currency = 'GBP' then 
    sum(itemPrice) + sum(shippingPrice) * 1.33
else
    case when currency = 'USD' then
    sum(itemPrice) + sum(shippingPrice) * 0.92
else 
    case when currency = 'CAD' then 
    sum(itemPrice) + sum(shippingPrice) * 0.65
else 
    case when currency = 'MXN' then
    sum(itemPrice) + sum(shippingPrice) * 0.0513 
else sum(itemPrice) + sum(shippingPrice)
end end end end
as turnover, currency from foo
group by currency
```

When I try to wrap all the cases in another `sum()` I get

> invalid use of group function

How would I do this best?

Comment: If you want a single value instead of one per currency, don't group on currency

Comment: Doesn't return the correct result then! @DBug

Comment: my guess is because of the nested cases?  @Barmar's solution is what I was driving towards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the `GROUP BY`, and do the `SUM` **outside** `CASE`

```
SELECT SUM((itemPrice + shippingPrice) *
        CASE currency
            WHEN 'GBP' THEN 1.33
            WHEN 'USD' THEN 0.92
            WHEN 'CAD' THEN 0.65
            WHEN 'MXN' THEN 0.0513
            ELSE 1.0
        END) AS turnover
FROM foo
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. It should only be `sum( ( itemPrice + shippingPrice) * ...)`, but now it's working fine!

Comment: The query in your question only multiplied the shipping price by the currency conversion, so that's what I did.

Comment: Since currency conversions change, you probably should put that in a table instead of hard-coding it in the `CASE`.

Comment: Those rates actually are in a redis instance that is updated every day, I just hard-coded it here for simplicity.